# Ionic Native: how to trigger some function at an absolute time

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to Mobile development and I am using Ionic Native. I want to trigger a function at a fixed time point, e.g. every 12:00 pm on Friday, no matter my App is running or not.

I guess I need to register this function into the system service level but have no idea how to achieve this. I currently run my App on Android but maybe IOS later. I assume the solution will be different.

Comment: Seems you need a customized plugin for this case.

Answer (score 0):

First: ionic is a css and angular directive and services framework  binding your app with Cordova framework. As general rule of thumb if something is unrelated on how your app look or feel  it is Cordova related issue

Second: It is not currently possible to keep running a code in background if the user kill your app in IOS.

if you want to run a background services in Andorid you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111968/run-service-when-ionic-cordova-app-when-its-closed)

If you want to push a notification you can add Cordova(or ngCordova) plugin for local notification[here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/). you can read