# how to use "cordova plugin background"

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, background

i wrote an application that schedule a daily check .
i use setInterval() to schedule the check.
problem is when the phone goes to sleep the check isn't happening.

i looked into a few  background plugins like :

cordova-plugin-background-app ,

cordova-plugin-background-mode

what i dont understand is how to combine it with my timing

i need to run the check only when the app is on ,

but i need to run even if the phone is sleeping or the app is in the background.

help will be appreciated

Raven Radio

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111968/run-service-when-ionic-cordova-app-when-its-closed

Comment: @Lord hope you are looking for this plugin - https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications